# How to manage all the various proof methods

Tags: isabelle

Is there a "generic" informal algorithm that users of Isabelle follow, when they are trying to prove something that isn't proved immediately by `auto` or `sledgehammer`? A kind of general way of figuring out, if `auto` needs additional lemmas, formulated by the user, to succeed or if better some other proof method is used.

A related question is: Is there maybe a table to be found somewhere with all the proof methods together with the context in which to apply them? When I'm reading through the  [Programming and Proving tutorial](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/prog-prove.pdf), the description of various methods (respectively variants of some methods, such as the many variant of `auto`) are scattered through the text, which constantly makes me go back and for between text and Isabelle code (which also leads to forgetting what exactly is used for what) and which results in a very inefficient workflow.

Answer (score 8):

No, there's no "generic" informal way. You can use `try0` which tries all standard proof methods (like `auto`, `blast`, `fastforce`, …) and/or `sledgehammer` which is more advanced.

After that, the fun part starts.

- Can this theorem be shown with simpler helper lemmas? You can use the command "sorry" for assuming that a lemma is true.
- How would I prove this on a piece of paper? And then try to do this proof in Isabelle.
- Ask for help :) Lots of people on stack overflow, #isabelle on freenode and the Isabelle mailing list are waiting for your questions.

For your second question: No, there's no such overview. Maybe someone should write one, but as mentioned before you can simply use `try0`.

Comment: There is also `try`, which does even more stuff (but it is rarely used because it is too broad to be helpful, I think).

Answer (score 7):

ammbauer's answer already covers lots of important stuff, but here are some more things that may help you:

- When the automation gets stuck at a certain point, look at the available premises and the goal at that point. What kind of simplification did you expect the system to do at that point? Why didn't it do it? Perhaps the corresponding rule is just not in the simp set (add it with `simp add:`) or some preconditions of the rule could not be proved (in that case, add enough facts so that they can be proved, or do it yourself in an additional step)
- Isar proofs are good. If you have some complicated goal, try breaking it down into smaller steps in Isar. If you have bigger auxiliary facts that may even be of more general interest, try pulling them out as auxiliary lemmas. Perhaps you can even generalise them a bit. Sometimes that even simplifies the proof.
- In the same vein: Too much information can confuse both you and Isabelle. You can introduce local definitions in Isar with `define x where "x = …"` and unfold them with `x_def`. This makes your goals smaller and cleaner and decreases the probability of the automation going down useless paths in its proof search.
- Isabelle does not automatically unfold definitions, so if you have a `definition`, and you want to unfold it for a proof, you have to do that yourself by using `unfolding foo_def` or `simp add: foo_def`.
- The defining equations of functions defined with `fun` or `primrec` *are* unfolding by anything using the simplifier (`simp`, `simp_all`, `force`, `auto`) unless the equations (`foo.simps`) have manually been deleted from the simp set. (by `lemmas [simp del] = foo.simps` or `declare [simp del] foo.simps`)
- Different proof methods are good at different things, and it takes some experience to know what method to use in what case. As a general rule, anything that requires only rewriting/simplification should be done with `simp` or `simp_all`. Anything related to classical reasoning (i.e. first-order logic or sets) calls for `blast`. If you need both rewriting and classical reasoning, try `auto` or `force`. Think of `auto` as a combination of `simp` and `blast`, and `force` is like an ‘all-or-nothing’ variant of `auto` that fails if it cannot solve the goal entirely. It also tries a little harder than `auto`.
- Most proof methods can take options. You probably already know `add:` and `del:` for `simp` and `simp_all`, and the equivalent `simp:`/`simp del:` for `auto`. However, the classical reasoners (`auto`, `blast`, `force`, etc.) also accept `intro:`, `dest:`, `elim:` and the corresponding `del:` options. These are for declaring introduction, destruction, and elimination rules.

Some more information on the classical reasoner:

- An introduction rule is a rule of the form `P ⟹ Q ⟹ R` that should be used whenever the goal has the form `R`, to replace it with `P` and `Q`
- A destruction rule is a rule of the form `P ⟹ Q ⟹ R` that should be used whenever a fact of the form `P` is in the premises to replace to goal `G` with the new goals `Q` and `R ⟹ G`.
- An elimination rule is something like `thm exE` (elimination of the existential quantifier). These are like a generalisation of destruction rules that also allow introducing new variables. These rules often appear in this like case distinctions.
- The classical reasoner used by `auto`, `blast`, `force` etc. will use the rules in the claset (i.e. that have been declared `intro`/`dest`/`elim`) automatically whenever appropriate. If doing that does not lead to a proof, the automation will backtrack at some point and try other rules. You can disable backtracking for specific rules by using `intro!:` instead of `intro:` (and analogously for the others). Then the automation will apply that rule whenever possible without ever looking back.
- The basic proof methods `rule`, `drule`, `erule` correspond to applying a single intro/dest/elim rule and are good for single step reasoning, e.g. in order to find out why automatic methods fail to make progress at a certain point. `intro` is like `rule` but applies the set of rules it is given iteratively until it is no longer possible.
- `safe` and `clarify` are occasionally useful. The former essentially strips away quantifiers and logical connectives (try it on a goal like `∀x. P x ∧ Q x ⟶ R x`) and the latter similarly tries to ‘clean up’ the goal. (I forgot what it does exactly, I just use it occasionally when I think it might be useful)

Comment: These are great tipps!

Comment: A clarification for myself. The classical reasoner is described in Chapter 14 of Isabelle a generic theorem prover (1994). But maybe there are newer updates?

Comment: isar-ref is the place to go for such things. Have a look at Section 9.4: http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/doc/isar-ref.pdf